# How is a 256x256 24-bit gradient PNG only 777 bytes?

Tags: image, file, compression, png, image-compression

**Here's the file in question:**

[image: Gradient PNG]

If you open this PNG image in an HEX-Editor you will notice this file is only 777 bytes large. How is this possible? Note that each pixel has a different color value!

A 24 bit 256x256 image that has unique pixels should be at least 197KBytes large.
256*256*3 bytes = 196608 bytes

Is this using some hidden feature of PNG files or using some kind of hack?

Edit: Just as a sanity check, I've encoded the PNG as Base64, and sure enough, it is as small.

```
data:image/png;base64,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
```

Comment: PNGs are still compressed, but the compression is supposed to be lossless compared to the compression of JPEG.

Comment: What kind of compression is this using? I've not been able to find a tool that can compress a 197KB PNG into a 0.7KB PNG (Compression ratio of 0.35%!).

Comment: The compression of PNG files is done in two phases, filtering, and then compression. In the filtering stage, we try and reduce the size of each pixel, buy coming up with a way to get there from the pixel before it, using a gradient like this, we can actually compress the file abnormally more then an arbitrary picture, because each pixel will be relatively the same as the one next to it.

Comment: Maybe [read this](https://medium.com/@duhroach/how-png-works-f1174e3cc7b7)?

Answer (score 5):

The image was constructed so that [PNG's filter type 4, the Paeth filter](https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG-Filters.html) perfectly predicts the pixel value for all lines after the first, except for a difference of 1 in the first green value, giving a green progression down and to the right. The first line, which is an increment of reds, uses filter type 1, Sub, which results in the series 1 0 0 1 0 0 ... You end up with 196,098 zeros, 511 ones, and 255 fours, which is highly compressible.